# Initialize array of pointers in a class and retrieve it in a different one

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, inheritance, polymorphism

I want to initialize an array of pointers in a file, `array.cpp`, and retrieve it in a different `main.cpp`.

I now have six headers/src files: `parent.h/cpp`, `childA.h/cpp`, `childB.h/cpp`.

```
class Parent(){
public:
    Parent();
    virtual void sayHi() = 0;
};

Parent::Parent() {}

class ChildA : Parent{
public:
    ChildA()
    void sayHi();

ChildA::ChildA()
void ChildA::sayHi(){
    std::cout << "Hello A!"
}

class ChildB : Parent{
public:
    ChildB()
    void sayHi();

ChildB::ChildB()
void ChildB::sayHi(){
    std::cout << "Hello B!"
}
```

I understand how to create an array of pointers that contain `ChildA()` and `ChildB()` in the `main.cpp` class:

```
Parent *children[3] = {new ChildA(), new ChildB(), new ChildA()}
```

What if I want to initialize this in a different file, say `array.cpp`, and retrieve it from `main.cpp`?

### My idea (not working)

My rough idea was to create define a class inside `array.h/cpp` as follows:

```
class Array(){
    Array();
    Parent *get_array();    // I don't know how to define it as an array of pointers
}
Array::Array()

Parent *Array::get_array() {
    Parent *array[] = { new ChildA(), new ChildB(), new Child() };
    return *array;
}
```

and in `main.cpp`:

```
Array array;
Parent *children[] = array.get_array();    // It cannot be initialized like this
```

This doesn't work and I don't know how to proceed from here.

Comment: OT: Note that this: `Parent *children[3] = {new ChildA(), new ChildB(), new ChildA()}` is quite _exception-unsafe_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply use a `std::vector` instead of C arrays:

```
class Array
{
public:
   Array() {}
   std::vector<Parent*> get_array();   
};

std::vector<Parent*> Array::get_array() {
   return { new ChildA(), new ChildB(), new Child() };
}

int main()
{
   Array a;
   std::vector<Parent*> res = a.get_array();

   res[0]->sayHi();
   res[1]->sayHi();
   res[2]->sayHi();

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: I would just add that a vector of _unique pointers_ might be much more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks. Would it be possible to access sayHi() simply as res[0]->sayHi() ?

Comment: @DanielLangr You are right. But the Q is not tagged with C++11.

Comment: @Gupta Nor with C++98/03. Nowadays, I believe C++11 is much more common. But that note was intended more for OP.

Comment: @DanielLangr I am not sure. Actually in SO, we have tags for C++11, 14, 17 and 20 but not for C++98 or 03. So I believe that when a Q is tagged with C++, it is either 98 or 03.

Comment: @Gupta There are tags for both [C++98 and C++03](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b03%20c%2b%2b98). I just refer to my experience, since I watch mostly questions tagged C++ only and, usually, C++11 is used in answers quite normally.

Comment: @DanielLangr Oh, my bad. Thanks for the references to the tags. I have hardly faced a Q with C++98 or C++03 tags. Yeah, I think it is better to take C++11 as the base standard for all C++ questions tagged with C++.